# android issues updating Listview due to filtering, with a custom base adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter, notifydatasetchanged, android-searchmanager

I'm facing issue by implementing a search mechanism on a `ListView` in Android.

- I currently display a list of companies in a `ListView`
- The `ListView` is linked to a custom `BaseAdapter` that ref a data model
- The data model handle the data gathering thru `HTTP requests`.

I succeed partly filtering : the identified companies are identified in the `listview`, but the rest of the companies (the ones that not match the searching constraint are still there), even if I removed them

Here is the code :

```
package org.x.activites;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.x.R;
import org.x.activites.utils.Analytics;
import org.x.adapters.listview.AbstractDynamicModel;
import org.x.adapters.listview.AbstractExtendedDynamicViewAdapter;
import org.x.adapters.listview.ViewHolder;
import org.x.application.Application;
import org.x.http.HTTPRequest;
import org.x.list.adapters.PartnerViewHolder;
import org.x.model.Partner;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView;

public class GeoPartnerActivity extends SherlockActivity {
    private ListView listView;
    PartnersModel partnersModel;
    PartnerListAdapter partnerAdpt;
    private SearchManager searchManager;
    private SearchView searchView;

    public GeoPartnerActivity() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_partner);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.partnerList);
        partnersModel = new PartnersModel();
        partnerAdpt = new PartnerListAdapter(partnersModel);
        listView.setAdapter(partnerAdpt);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_partners, menu);
        searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
        if (null != searchView) {
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
            searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        }

        SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }

            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(query)) {
                    listView.clearTextFilter();
                }
                else {
                    listView.setFilterText(query);
                }
                partnerAdpt.getFilter().filter(query);
                return true;
            }
        };

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);
        searchView.setQueryHint("Salut StackExchange");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public class PartnersModel extends AbstractDynamicModel<Partner> {

        public PartnersModel() {
        }

        private HTTPRequest createRequest() {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("currentIndex", getElements().size() + ""));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("partnersNumber", "5"));

            return new HTTPRequest("http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/partners", nameValuePairs);
        }

        @Override
        protected BackgroundTask createBackgroundTask() {
            BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(GeoPartnerActivity.this, createRequest()) {
                List<Partner> lastLoaded = new ArrayList<Partner>();

                @Override
                protected List<Partner> getLoadedElements() {
                    return lastLoaded;
                }

                @Override
                protected void handleSuccess(Object object) {
                    lastLoaded.clear();
                    try {
                        JSONArray array = (JSONArray) object;
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) array.get(i);

                            Partner partner = new Partner(jsonObject);

                            lastLoaded.add(partner);
                        }

                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            };
            return backgroundTask;
        }

        @Override
        public List<Partner> getElements() {
            return super.getElements();
        }

        @Override
        protected Context getContext() {
            return GeoPartnerActivity.this;
        }

    }

    private class PartnerListAdapter extends AbstractExtendedDynamicViewAdapter<Partner> implements Filterable {

        private PartnersModel partnerList, partnerFullList;
        private PartnerFilter partnerFilter;

        public PartnerListAdapter(PartnersModel model) {
            super(GeoPartnerActivity.this, model);
            partnerList = model;
            partnerFullList = new PartnersModel();
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            if (partnerFilter == null) {
                partnerFilter = new PartnerFilter();
            }
            return partnerFilter;
        }

        public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
            super.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected int getResourceID() {
            return PartnerViewHolder.ResourceId;
        }

        @Override
        protected ViewHolder createViewHolder(View convertView) {
            return new PartnerViewHolder(convertView);
        }

        public class PartnerFilter extends Filter {

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                List<Partner> partnerFilteredList = new ArrayList<Partner>();
                for (Iterator<Partner> iterator = partnerList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {

                    Partner partner = iterator.next();
                    partnerFullList.getElements().add(partner);

                    if (false == partner.getName().toUpperCase().contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
                        partnerFilteredList.add(partner);
                    }
                }
                results.values = partnerFilteredList;
                results.count = partnerFilteredList.size();

                return results;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results.count == 0)
                    partnerAdpt.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                else {
                    for (Iterator<Partner> iterator = ((List<Partner>) results.values).iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                        Partner p = (Partner) iterator.next();
                        if (partnerAdpt.partnerList.getElements().remove(p));
                            p.setName("del-> " + p.getName());  
                    }

                    //listView.setAdapter(null);
                    //listView.setAdapter(new PartnerListAdapter(partnerList));
                    ((PartnerListAdapter) listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                    listView.refreshDrawableState();
                    listView.invalidateViews();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the menu layout

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/toolbar_find"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Search">
    </item>
</menu>
```

And here is screenshot before filtering :

[image]

And after :

[image]

I have tagged the name of the items with a "del->", so all of them are identified, but not removed from the list !!!

Edit :

Here is the top adapter AbstractDynamicViewAdapter:

```
public abstract class AbstractDynamicViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    protected final Context _context;

    protected final ArrayList<AdapterItem> _list;

    private final LayoutInflater _inflater;

    private final int _progressResourceId;
    private final int _unavailableResourceId;
    private final int _emptyResourceId;

    protected boolean _isInitialization = false;
    protected boolean _isRequestSubmited = false;

    public AbstractDynamicViewAdapter(Context context, int progressResourceId, int unavailableResourceId,
            int emptyResourceId) {
        _context = context;
        _inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        _list = new ArrayList<AdapterItem>();

        _progressResourceId = progressResourceId;
        _unavailableResourceId = unavailableResourceId;
        _emptyResourceId = emptyResourceId;
    }

    protected abstract View onDataView(int position, AdapterItem item, View convertView, ViewGroup parent);

    protected abstract void onDataLoad();

    protected abstract boolean isMoreToLoad();

    protected abstract void onSubmitDataRequest();

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return _list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        Object result = null;

        if (position < _list.size()) {
            result = _list.get(position);
        }

        return result;
    }

@Override
/* Override this method when implementing stable id */
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (_list.size() > position) {
        AdapterItem item = _list.get(position);

        if (item.viewType == ViewType.Data) {
            convertView = onDataView(position, item, convertView, parent);
        }
        else {
            int resourceid = getResourceByViewType(item.viewType);
            convertView = tryInflateView(convertView, resourceid, parent);
            tryCreateViewHolder(convertView, item, resourceid);

            if (!_isRequestSubmited && item.viewType == ViewType.Progress) {
                submitDataRequest();
            }
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}
protected int getResourceByViewType(ViewType expectedType) {
    int result = 0;

    switch (expectedType) {
        case Progress:
            result = _progressResourceId;
            break;
        case Unavailable:
            result = _unavailableResourceId;
            break;
        case Empty:
            result = _emptyResourceId;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return result;
}

protected void tryCreateViewHolder(View viewSource, AdapterItem item, int resourceId) {
    ViewHolder viewItem = (ViewHolder) viewSource.getTag();
    if (viewItem == null) {
        viewItem = new ViewHolder(viewSource, resourceId);
    }
}

protected View tryInflateView(View viewSource, int resourceId, ViewGroup parent) {
    View result = null;

    if (viewSource != null && viewSource.getTag() != null) {
        ViewHolder viewItem = (ViewHolder) viewSource.getTag();
        // try to re-use view if it has the same type
        if (viewItem != null && viewItem.resourceId == resourceId) {
            result = viewSource;
        }
    }

    if (result == null) {
        // create new view
        result = _inflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);
    }

    return result;
}

    protected void addItem(Object value, Object tag) {
        AdapterItem item = new AdapterItem(value, tag);
        _list.add(item);
    }

    protected void removeItem(Object item) {
        _list.remove(item);
    }

    protected void addUnavailableItem() {
        AdapterItem item = new AdapterItem(ViewType.Unavailable);
        _list.add(item);
    }

    protected void submitDataRequest() {
        showProgress();
        onSubmitDataRequest();
        _isRequestSubmited = true;
    }

    protected void setDataCompleted() {
        _list.clear();
        onDataLoad();
        if (isMoreToLoad()) {
            showProgress();
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();

        _isRequestSubmited = false;
    }

    private void removeAnyBut(ViewType type) {
        if (type != ViewType.Progress) {
            tryEndProgress();
        }

        if (type != ViewType.Empty) {
            tryEndEmpty();
        }

        if (type != ViewType.Unavailable) {
            tryEndUnavailable();
        }
    }

    private void tryShowItem(ViewType type) {
        removeAnyBut(type);

        if (_list.size() == 0 || _list.get(_list.size() - 1).viewType != type) {
            _list.add(new AdapterItem(type));
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    protected void showUnavailable() {
        tryShowItem(ViewType.Unavailable);
    }

    protected void showProgress() {
        tryShowItem(ViewType.Progress);
    }

    protected void showEmpty() {
        tryShowItem(ViewType.Empty);
    }

    private void tryRemoveItem(ViewType type) {
        if (_list.size() > 0 && _list.get(_list.size() - 1).viewType == type) {
            _list.remove(_list.size() - 1);
        }
    }

    protected void tryEndProgress() {
        tryRemoveItem(ViewType.Progress);
    }

    protected void tryEndUnavailable() {
        tryRemoveItem(ViewType.Unavailable);
    }

    protected void tryEndEmpty() {
        tryRemoveItem(ViewType.Empty);
    }

}
```

And the middle adapter AbstractExtendedDynamicViewAdapter :

```
public abstract class AbstractExtendedDynamicViewAdapter<T> extends AbstractDynamicViewAdapter {
    private final AbstractDynamicModel<T> _model;

    private boolean offlineModedataLoaded = false;

    private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void dispatchMessage(Message msg) {
            setDataCompleted();
        }
    };

    public AbstractExtendedDynamicViewAdapter(Context context, AbstractDynamicModel<T> model) {
        super(context, R.layout.progress_item, R.layout.unavailable_item, R.layout.empty_item);

        _model = model;
        _model.setLoadCompleted(handler);
        submitDataRequest();
    }

    @Override
    public View onDataView(int position, AdapterItem item, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = tryInflateView(convertView, getResourceID(), parent);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        if (viewHolder == null) {
            viewHolder = createViewHolder(convertView);
        }
        viewHolder.render(item);
        return convertView;
    }
    public boolean removeElement(Object obj) {
        //return _list.remove(obj);
        return _model.getElements().remove(obj);
    }

    protected abstract int getResourceID();

    protected abstract ViewHolder createViewHolder(View convertView);

    @Override
    protected boolean isMoreToLoad() {
        if (Utils.isConnected(_context)) {
            offlineModedataLoaded = true;
            return true;
        }
        else
            if (false == offlineModedataLoaded) {
                offlineModedataLoaded = true;
                return true;
            }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDataLoad() {
        if (_model.getElements().isEmpty()) {
            addUnavailableItem();
            showUnavailable();
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < _model.getElements().size(); i++) {

                addItem(_model.getElements().get(i), null);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSubmitDataRequest() {
        _model.loadMore();
    }

}
```

Comment: base class of adapter is not using the same instance of PartnersModel as you are filtering ...

Comment: What is "AbstractExtendedDynamicViewAdapter" ?

Comment: @kozaxinan, AbstractExtendedDynamicViewAdapter is a project generic extension for the baseAdapter

Comment: @Selvin, I didn't get what you mean, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (partnerAdpt.partnerList.getElements().remove(p));
                            p.setName("del-> " + p.getName());
```

With this code you only update filtered result. You should remove this values from the list you put in adapter with this code:

```
super(GeoPartnerActivity.this, model);
```

Try to get "model" data from adapter (not from abstract) and remove "p".

Comment: I have tried all ways I could imagine... no success. From your suggestion, I tried changing to 'partnersModel.getElements.remove(p);' but nothing affected. Is that correct ?

Comment: You still use local varaiable. You should use the list in your baseadapter. Please add a method to get model from baseadapter.

Comment: Can you post your adapter class too.

Comment: In the edited question, I added the following method `public ArrayList<AdapterItem> getAdapterItemList() { return _list;}`, and then use it as the following `getAdapterItemList().remove(p);` but nothing changed !

Comment: Actually it is looking like it is missing some method or class, isnt it?

Comment: Yes..but nothing deeply link to the context. Would this help you ?

Comment: Somehow you lose your list variable with your one of local values. But make it harder to find it. Can you please try "partnerList.getElements().remove(p)" instead of "partnerAdpt.partnerList.getElements().remove(p)" if it is not help i need to see all code of this part.

Comment: @anthony did you understand your problem. If you want help i need to see other parts or this custom class.

Comment: I am glad to help. I suggest you to simplify the code. You Keep a lot of local instance. Which suggestion fixed, i want to update my answer for correct fix. @anthony

Comment: I think i Found your problem. You show list from _list with adapterItem but you try to remove it from model you Keep at higher level. Try to remove your filter from _list which in adapter. But you need to remove right instance.